# HtmlUnit - scraping data

Tags: java, htmlunit

How using HtmlUnit I can extract page which contains javascript as HTML? I found sample code as below but not working.

```java
public class Downloader {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

            try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
                final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/");
                System.out.println(page.asText());
            }
            System.out.println("END");
        }
}
```

With this code I landing in infinite loop. I don't know why. If I open above site in firefox inspector I can see full HTML code after executing javascript. How I can reach the same result with HtmlUnit. It is possible? Maybe I should using any other library? Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know you'r entering in infinite loop? Try to run in debug and pause when you think you will go stuck. Where would you stop in code?

Comment: Maybe not infinite loop but I stuck in webClient.getPage(...). Program working and working but nothing happend.

Comment: Try to add `webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` as the first line of your `try` block

Comment: Nothing change.

Comment: Maybe `webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10)`, so you can have a timeout for fetching the page.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setTimeout-int-

Comment: Timeout throw TimeoutException but not fetching anything. Moreover If I try send request to different site for example: webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com") it normally give me data and stop program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlUnit tends to have a lot of problems with interpreting javascript. If you are just looking for the game data, you might be more successful otherwise:
https://github.com/gingeleski/odds-portal-scraper

Anyways, i managed to get the code working with changing the BrowserVersion:
`final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)`